# Unable to get command output from chef recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, recipe

I have a command which need to be run on Unix/win Env's  (using knife ) :

```
execute "smart_table" do
  command "su -  #{username} -c ' myutils -PATH  #{file_name} -OVERWRITE '" 
  action :run
end
```

this command has an output which should be parsed for some keyword inside.

I've read about open3 etc .. but unable  to implement .

i will appreciate an example .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way with `Mixin::shellout`:

```rb
ruby_block "smart_table" do
  block do
    Chef::Resource::RubyBlock.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)      
    command = "su -  #{username} -c ' myutils -PATH  #{file_name} -OVERWRITE '" 
    command_out = shell_out(command)
    p command_out.stdout
  end
  action :create
end
```

Comment: For others that find this, the mixin is already available in resources in recent versions of Chef, and you should _never_ make global DSL changes in a resource like this.